# Implement html5 on asp:textboxes

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, validation, textbox

I cant Implement html 5 on asp:textboxes, everything I found on the internet was implemented on input: not on asp:textboxes

now I found a very useful validator for textboxes, however, I can't make it work with asp:textbox

here are the codes:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').h5Validate();
});
 </script>

<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Bob" title="Your name is required." required />
```

I want to make it work with asp:textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asp:textbox` is a server side tag and after client request, server will return html with `<input>`; so all options for `<input>` also can be used for `asp:textbox`.